# How to retrieve Stripe Subscription using customer email

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Given a customer's email address how do I access their subscriptions, specifically their subscription status. There is only 1 subscription service I provide, so any queries should only bring up one result.

e.g.

```
import stripe  

def functionA(customer_email):
    ...
    return customer_sub

sub  = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(functionA("xyz@gmail.com"))
status = sub.status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to get the customer ID, either using [list](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=python#list_customers-email) (case-sensitive) or [search](https://stripe.com/docs/search#customers-email-search) (case insensitive):

```
stripe.Customer.list(email="Test@example.com")
stripe.Customer.search(query="email:'test@example.com'")
```

then you can [list Subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-customer) for that customer id:

```
stripe.Subscription.list(customer="cus_123")
```